Lights and outlets in 2 bathrooms out at same time
Out of the blue a couple of days ago the lights and outlets in our master bathroom Suddenly went out. Not only that, but the lights and outlets in the guest bathroom did too.
I turned off all the breakers and then steadily turned each back on. That didn’t work. So I went to Home Depot and got the exact GE two-pole breakers and replaced them where each is labeled on the panel. Still didn’t work.
I read about resetting the GCFI outlets and tried that. It worked, but only for the outlets in both rooms. The lights are still off.
Can anyone please help me?  Thank you
The slot names:
1 Lights 1 pole 15 A
2 6DO, GFI 1 pole 20A
3 Lights 2 poles shared with
4 no idea what it says 2 Pole 20A
5 Kitchen GFI 2 poles shared with
6 Kitchen GFI 2 poles 20A
7 Bath, GFI 2 poles shared with
8 Bed 3 (guest bed) 2 poles 20A
9 Bed 2, Master 1 pole 20A
10-13 22KA all connected with 200 on long switch
14 fan 1 pole 15A
15 A/C 2 pole shared with
16 A/C 2 pole 40A
17 garbage disposal 2 pole shared with
18 Dishwasher 2 Pole 20A
19 washer 2 pole shared with
20 dryer 2 pole 20A
21 microwave 2 pole shared with
22 nook (recessed, decorative place on wall) 2 pole 20A

Here is the panel names for each breaker:

Breakers are usually the last to go bad/need replacement, unless tested to be bad.  Quite possible there is a push in connection that is bad, the ones where the wire is pushed in at the back of outlets/switches to save time.

Are you sure you’ve found all the gfci receptacles in the house? Garage, outdoor, kitchen, another bathroom…

Very likely a different GFCI that has not yet been reset.

Do all GFCI outlets have the red black test/reset buttons?

They should have test/reset, but the colours/design might be different.

They will always have the two buttons, but the buttons may be the same color as the faceplate.

Is it common to put lights on a GFCI circuit?
